# Matplotlib cumulative frequency graph with extra line in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

When I run my code to generate a graph of the relative cumulative frequencies of a dataset, my graphs come out with a line straight down at the point the graph crosses the line `y=1` on the right side, [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Hvy.png).

The y-axis is limited to the range `y=0` to `y=1`, representing 0% to 100% of the cumulative frequency, once the graph reached `y=1`, or 100%, it *should* continue at `y=1` until the upper limit of the x-axis, which goes from `x=0` to `x=2`, similar to [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw2iU.png).

Is there some way to ensure that the historgram contiues at `y=1` after `y=1` has been reached? I need my x-axis to remain on the range [0,2] and the y-axis on the range [0,1].

Here is my Python code I use to generate my graphs:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
# ...
plt.ylabel('Relative Cumulative Frequency')
plt.xlabel('Normalized Eigenvalues')
plt.hist(e.real, bins = 50, normed=1, histtype='step', cumulative=True)
# Limit X and Y ranges   
plt.xlim(0, 2)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
```

Thanks, Max

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating your own bins and [setting the last bin to `np.Inf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29829041/3734222):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
...
x = np.random.rand(100,1)

plt.ylabel('Relative Cumulative Frequency')
plt.xlabel('Normalized Eigenvalues')

binsCnt = 50
bins = np.append(np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), binsCnt), [np.inf])
plt.hist(x, bins = bins, normed=1, histtype='step', cumulative=True)
# Limit X and Y ranges
plt.xlim(0, 2)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: When I run the code you put, I get an error at this line: `>>> plt.hist(x,normed=1,bins=bins,histtype='step',cumulative=1)` ,Which results in this message:
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ymin' referenced before assignment`.

Comment: @MaxSamuels I don't see any local variable ymin. Maybe you forgot global somewhere? What is ymin?

Comment: Oh, sorry, Forgot to add screenshot to my [error message](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1O6LM.png).